# What is a centered probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory

I have been reading about probability measures in some papers and I have found the name"centered probability measure" but I am not very sure what it is, I suppose that a proability measure $\mu$ is a centered probability measure if $\int_\mathbb{R}x\mu(dx)=0$ but I am not sure, anyone knows the definition?

Any help or advice is welcoming, thanks!.

Comment: $\int_\mathbb{R}\mu(dx)=1$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot a "$x$", sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability measure $\mu$ is centered if $\int_\mathbb R x \mu(dx) = 0$, that is, if it represents the distribution of a random variable with zero mean.

Comment: Thanks for the help.